# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.target.value')

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a React Native project and I'm trying to make a Login form.

But I have some trouble to handle the text change in the `TextInput`.

**My login form code**

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  onLogin() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    Alert.alert('Credentials', `${email} + ${password}`);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      email: event.target.value,
      password: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.form}>
          <Title>Connectez-vous</Title>
          <TextInput
            style={{ backgroundColor: '#f8f8ff' }}
            value={email}
            onChangeText={this.handleChange}
            label="Adresse email"
            mode="outlined"
          />
          <TextInput
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#f8f8ff',
            }}
            value={password}
            onChangeText={this.handleChange}
            label="Mot de passe"
            mode="outlined"
            secureTextEntry
          />
          <Button
            mode="outlined"
            onPress={() => this.onLogin}
            style={{ marginTop: '5%', marginHorizontal: '25%' }}
          >
            Connexion
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I try to write something in the TextInput I got the error : `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.target.value')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with below code::

```js
handleChange(inputText) {
    this.setState({
      email: inputText,
    });
}

handleEmailChange(inputText) {
    this.setState({
      email: inputText,
    });
}

handlePasswordChange(inputText) {
    this.setState({
      password: inputText,
    });
}

<TextInput
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#f8f8ff' }}
        value={email}
        onChangeText={this.handleChange}
        label="Adresse email"
        mode="outlined"
/>
```

or you can use like this also

```js
<TextInput
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#f8f8ff' }}
        value={email}
        onChangeText={(email) => { this.setState({ email }) }}
        label="Adresse email"
        mode="outlined"
/>

<TextInput
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#f8f8ff' }}
        value={email}
        onChangeText={(password) => { this.setState({ password}) }}
        label="Password"
        mode="outlined"
/>
```

I think this will work.. I have updated the `onChangeText` props

Comment: Nothing has changed

Comment: @seiju, My bad, `e` is not an event, actually it is text so, we don't need to to have use `e.target.value`, you can directly use `e` or just rename to `inputText`. You can read more about this from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext) , If you want to use `e.target.value` then use `onChange` props

Comment: What do you mean by "you can directly use e" ? Can you update your answer to explain ?

Comment: @seiju, I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: If I change my code as your answer my email and my password are sharing the same input. So I changed my code to onChange but now I have another error, please have a look at my edit

Comment: The reason for this is that you are setting newlyText to both i.e. `email` and `password`. Either create 2 handler for both like, `onEmailChange` and `onPasswordChange` instead of `handleChange`

Comment: @seiju, I also updated my answer for your reference.

Comment: Ok it works if I use 2 different functions to handleChange the input texts for email and password but there is no way to use only one function for both ?
Also I can't use `onChangeText={(email) => {this.setState({email})}}` because I already declare email and password at the beginning of my render.

Comment: Then you can use like `onChangeText={(emailText) => {this.setState({email: emailText})}}`

Comment: I try this and I get this.setState is not a function? What could be the cause of that?

Comment: @MattLaszcz, Can you share your entire file?

Comment: @MujiburRehmanAnsari I actually solved my issue but Now I cannot get it to render on my page from the store.

Comment: @MattLaszcz, I can't help you until I see your code, so I requested to please share it.

Comment: how to write the same code code for functional component

Answer (score 1):

You're using React Native and *not* React DOM. `<TextInput />`'s `onChangeText` [does not pass an event](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput) as the first argument, just a plain string. In general, event handling code you see from regular React examples that utilize the DOM don't transfer well here because those events don't actually exist in their native counterparts.

You need to change your current event handling code from this

```
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      email: event.target.value,
      password: event.target.value,
    });
  }
```

to this:

```
  handleChange(text) {
    this.setState({
      email: text,
      password: text,
    });
  }
```

However, this will also fail because as @Rawrplus mentioned, you have not bound the method to the context. `this` in JavaScript is special and doesn't work like it does in other languages and refers to the execution context of a method rather than the definition context. This can be fixed by using arrow functions:

```
  handleChange = (text) => {
    this.setState({
      email: text,
      password: text,
    });
  }
```

Comment: I use eslint and I can't use `handleChange = (text) =>` because of an unexpected token '='

Comment: Then update eslint. This is valid javascript syntax and has been for quite some time now.

Answer (score 0):

That's not working as expected because `react-native` has 2 different `onChange` functions:

```js
<TextInput 
    onChange={e => console.log(e.nativeEvent.text)}
    onChangeText={text => console.log(text)} />
```

The first one (`onChange`), is not structured like on the web:

```js
event : {
    nativeEvent : {
        eventCount,
        target,
        text
    }
}
```

and the second one, which you appear to be using only gives you the text as a string so you don't have to dig through layers of event properties to get it. You will either have to change your handler function to expect text or bind to `onChange` rather than `onChangeText` on the `TextInput`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method :

```
this.state = {
  email: '13119165220',
}
onChangeText={text => this.setState({ email: text })}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `onLogin` fucntion will display nothing, because you have not bound the function to your `class`, so `this` just points to the `_global` object instead of `class`.

- So either, explicitly bind the method

  ```
  this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this)
  ```
- or more preferably [start using arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

  ```
  onLogin = () => {
    const { email, password } = this.state
    Alert.alert('Credentials', `${email} + ${password}`);
  }
  ```

As to the text-handling, `<TextInput>` component already has pre-defined `onTextChange` property, which accepts the inptu directly, instead of `event` which is reserved for `onChange`. You've essentially meshed the two together, so of course it doesn't work.

```
handleEmailChange = (textVal) => this.setState({
  email: textVal
})

<TextInput
  // ... other props
  onTextChange={this.handleEmailChange}
/>
```

Comment: The TextInput component is from react-native-paper library

Comment: That's just styling. `TextInput` itself is pre-defined as default export in `react-native`